# Can't launch CentOS 7.6 installer if PC has M.2 NVMe PCIe SSD

Tags: linux, centos, ssd, nvme

A PC has a Toshiba 512 GB NVMe PCIe SSD. Windows 10 has been installed on it and boots OK.

When trying to install CentOS 7.6 on this SSD, the system hangs during boot, and I  can't enter the CentOS installer. CentOS 7.6 will start the installer OK if the SSD is removed.

How may I resolve this to successfully install CentOS 7.6?

=== Update

SSD is Toshiba KBG30ZMS512G

I found this:

https://www.avnet.com/shop/emea/products/toshiba-memory/kbg30zms512g-3074457345636157125/

Model of PC, sorry this I can't provide, it is a server type (skylake) of machine.

Comment: Please advise the make and model of the PC, and the model of that Samsun NVMe drive. Please answer by adding that information to the original question with [edit], instead of Add Comment, for Comments get pushed off the screen by new comments.